# Multi Lingual Text display in Java jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, multilingual, jtextarea

I am receiving some Text from the MDB file which is not in English (look like french).
MS Access Displays it properly. I need to display it jTextField.
How this can be done?

I can not have predefined list of strings as the data is user entered.
String is saved as Short Text in the MS Access DB

Comment: Your text doesn't display correctly in the GUI? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Is this dealing with `JTextField` (body) or `JTextArea` (title)?  By the way, be careful to get the upper/lower case of class names right.  The J2SE classes start with an upper case letter.